# Вывод текст из DataGridView в Label

Tags: c#, datagridview

Как вывести текст из ячейки `DataGridView` в `Label`? Т.е. пишу в ячейку `DataGrid` текст, и он сразу же повторяется в `Label`.
Допустим, `label1.text = textBox1.text` - здесь всё просто: пишу текст, и он сразу же выводится, а вот из `DataGridView` в `Label` у меня никак не получается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

у `DataGridView` есть событие `CellValueChanged`. Можно в этом случае его использовать:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // Здесь проверяем индекс нужной Вам ячейки
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.RowIndex == 0)
    {
        label1.Text = dataGridView1[0, 0].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Подробнее:
[https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Спасибо Вам за ответ. Тут ситуация такая пока курсор находится в ячейке, текст в label не меняется и вот вся проблема в этом и заключается, что мне надо когда пишется в настоящее время текст в datagrid он сразу же должен и в label появляться.

Comment: Глубочайшие мои извинения, всё-таки подошло, спасибо огромное!!!.

Comment: @Евгений если ответ вас устраивает, не забудьте принять его (галочка слева от ответа).